# How to implement singleton pattern using ormlite in Android

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, ormlite

I've been testing various orm in Android to make the object-relational-mapping in an app I'm currently developing.

I have made a class diagram and I have found it useful to implement the Singleton pattern in some classes.

As the Singleton Pattern states the singleton class has to make the constructor  of the class private to enforce an unique instance of the class.

Considering this from the ORMlite help page:

> 2.1.3 Adding a No-Argument-Constructor
>
> After you have added the class and field annotations, you will also
>   need to add a no-argument constructor with at least package
>   visibility. When an object is returned from a query, ORMLite
>   constructs the object using Java reflection and a constructor needs to
>   be called.

How can I implement this pattern using ORMLite?, I will give an example:

The class ColectorPrincipal represents the user of my app, since there is only 1 person at time using the app I want to make sure there is only 1 instance of this class at time.

```
public class ColectorPrincipal extends Persona {

    @DatabaseField(index=true)
    private String numeroColeccionActual;
    private static ColectorPrincipal colectorPrincipal;
    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int colectorPrincipalID;
    @DatabaseField(foreign=true)
    private ArrayList<Viaje> viajes;
    @DatabaseField(foreign=true)
    private ArrayList<Proyecto> proyectos;
    @DatabaseField
    private int tipoCapturaDatos;

    /**
     * 
     * @param usuario
     * @param contraseña
     */
    private ColectorPrincipal(String usuario, String contraseña){
        super(usuario, contraseña);
        setusuario(new Usuario(usuario, contraseña));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param usuario
     * @param contraseña
     */
    public static ColectorPrincipal getColectorPrincipal(String usuario, String contraseña){
        if (colectorPrincipal == null) {
            colectorPrincipal=new ColectorPrincipal(usuario, contraseña);
        }
        return colectorPrincipal;
    }
...

}
```

This class have some transient attributes, and some persistent.

This class also extends from another class called Persona that represents a person so it has data like names, phone, address ... this attributes are persistent but the class Person is not persistent since I want to store the data from both classes in a single table.

```
public class Persona {

    @DatabaseField
    private String nombres;
    @DatabaseField
    private String apellidos;
    @DatabaseField
    private String direccion;
    @DatabaseField
    private String telefono;
    @DatabaseField
    private String institucion;
    private Usuario usuario;

    public Persona(){

    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param apellidos
     * @param nombres
     */
    public Persona(String apellidos, String nombres){

    }
    ...
}
```

Is possible to make ORMLite instantiate the class tru the singleton method **getColectorPrincipal**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your requirements here.

> I have made a class diagram and I have found it useful to implement the Singleton pattern in some classes.

It really doesn't make sense to have your database entities be singletons.  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) needs to instantiate instances of your `ColectorPrincipal` if it gets it from the database.

> This is one of my singleton classes I want to make persistent it represents an user of my app.

So you only have one user in your entire JVM?  I don't get it.

If you want to retrieve a singleton from the database, you might consider a wrapping class.  The wrapping class would enforce the singleton but it would initialize it's information from the database using another entity.

I'm not sure it helps but a newer feature of [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is support for an `ObjectFactory` which can be [set on the DAO](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#setObjectFactory%28com.j256.ormlite.table.ObjectFactory%29).  This factory allows you to control the instantiation of the object.  Here are the [javadocs for `ObjectFactory`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/ObjectFactory.html).

> Is possible to use ORMLite without the public constructor?

The constructor does not have to be public.  I believe package privileges works.

**Edit:**

It sounds like what you are looking for is that you want one user to be logged in at a time.
I'd just create an instance of `UserLogin` in the table when the user logs in that will then be deleted when the user logs out.  Then when the user goes to login, you see if there are any valid entries in the `UserLogin` table.

Comment: I will try to explain my self,
My Android will only have 1 user at time, the user can logout and then other users can login but only 1 at time.
So I will apply the singleton pattern to make sure only 1 instance of that class can be made. The purpose of this pattern is to ensure only that instance of the class is created during the app runtime.

Comment: Then I'd just create an instance of `UserLogin` in the table that will be deleted when the user logs out.  Then when the user goes to login, you see if there are any valid entries in the `UserLogin` table.

Comment: (I edited the question a little bit).
You are suggesting me to create a table UserLogin that stores the user logged in? and delete the row when the user logout?

Comment: Yes @dhampir.  That would work fine.  Or mark the `userLogin.setActive(false);` or something and update it.  Then your code could look for the active logins and throw an error if anyone else is still logged in.